# Java android studio get number from EditText

Tags: java, android

I have a EditText that is set to number but am not sure how to get the value entered into the main.activity.java. Please help. I also want it to be a number integer not string so that I can perform operations with it. Thanks.

I know that this is how to do it for a string but not sure how to do it for an integer/number.

```
 waketimeEnter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.waketime_enter);

 public void buttonClick(View view) {

    String waketime = String.valueOf(waketimeEnter.getText());
    sleepNumber.setText(waketime);


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since what you want it's on an `EditText` you'll have to parse it, here's an example to how to do it :

```
int number = Integer.parseInt(waketimeEnter.getText().toString());
```

Then since you want to put it as a `text` with `setText()` function it needs a `String` so a trick could be this :

```
sleepNumber.setText(String.valueOf(number));
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert String to integer -

```
String waketime = String.valueOf(waketimeEnter.getText());
int number = Integer.parseInt(waketime);
//Do whatever you want with number
sleepNumber.setText(waketime);
```

**EDIT** -

Add this line to your EditText -

```
android:inputType="number"
```

So that the user can't enter a non-integral value. Then this will work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
waketimeEnter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.waketime_enter); 

 public void buttonClick(View view) {

    int waketime = Integer.parseInt(waketimeEnter.getText().toString());
    sleepNumber.setText(waketime);


}
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
waketimeEnter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.waketime_enter);

        public void buttonClick(View view) {

            String waketime = String.valueOf(waketimeEnter.getText());
            sleepNumber.setText(waketime+"");


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with following code:

```
int waketime = Integer.valueOf(waketimeEnter.getText().toString());
sleepNumber.setText(String.valueOf(waketime));
```